# Forwarding http package in java

Tags: java, http, sockets, proxy, inputstream

I'm trying to write a HTTP proxy-server in java. My application takes a GET request from a browser and forwards it to its destination. I would like to read the headers of response package and then forward it back to the browser. This works great for me with text/html-content aslong as its not encoded in gzip. I've tried multiple ways to do this and I'm currently using a `DataInputStream` and a `DataOutputStream` but the browser only shows weird symbols.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
ArrayList<String> headerlist = new ArrayList<String>();
InputStream input = clientsocket.getInputStream();
dis = new DataInputStream(input);
serverinputstream = new InputStreamReader(input);
bufferreader = new BufferedReader(serverinputstream);

while(!(line = bufferedreader.readLine()).equals("")) {          
      headerlist.add(line);
    }

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(serveroutputstream, false);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(serveroutputstream);

for (int i = 0; i < headerlist.size(); i++) {
    pw.println(headerlist.get(i));  
}       
pw.println();

int bit;
while((bit = dis.read()) != -1) {
    out.writeByte(bit);
}
out.flush();
dis.close();
out.close();
```

This code only handles data that isnt plain text but it doesnt seem to be working. Should I use another method or I am just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overcomplicating things a bit.  Your proxy is just forwarding a request on to another destination.  There's no reason for it to care about whether it is forwarding text or binary data.  It should make no difference.

There's also no reason to read and write the headers individually.  All you should need to do is copy the entire request body to the new output-stream.

What about something like:

```
//...
InputStream input = clientsocket.getInputStream();
streamCopy(input, serveroutputstream);

//...


public void streamCopy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want to read the headers invididually because I want to be able to filter the data if its plain text. I've also already tried using a buffer like in your example, but with the same results.